# How do I render dynamic data stored in db for every second in yii

Tags: javascript, timer, automation

I want to know the number of registrations every second. Via AJAX, we retrieve the data on some event e.g., click, but then without clicking  dynamically data should fetched from db. 
something like it should automatically refresh and get the values.

It fetches on refreshing page or event based but without any of those how do I get the results.

Can this be done? Can anyone guide me on how I can achieve this. I am also not sure what tag I should apply. If I'm not clear please let me know I will elaborate.

```
  <script>

getFeed();

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function ()
   {
     getFeed();
      if (last_timestamp === undefined)
     {
    clearInterval(auto_refresh);
    last_timestamp = -1;
       }

   }, (1000 * 60)); // refresh every 60 seconds



 var last_timestamp = 0;
function getFeed()
{


    $.ajax({
        type        : 'GET',
        url         : '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/mycontroller/chart',
        data        : null,
        dataType    : 'html',
        success:function(data){
            $("#chart").html(data);
        },
    });


}
     </script>


 <div id="chart">

 </div>
```

The code above doesn't retrieve the result automatically after 60 second. How do I call an action on every second and not on any event or refresh page?

Comment: try searching for `node js`

Answer (score 0):

As fas as i know your requirement can not be achived with PHP and PHP frameworks as a main technologies.

You need to use [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) protocol over HTTP protocol to do this. Check below technologies which are build for WebSocket programing.

1. [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/) (Popular now a days)
2. [Socket IO](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, understand that this is not a Yii issue. The fact that your server code is written in PHP/Yii is just a co-incidence.

Then, understand that the server cannot control this, so a solution should ideally be found for the browser. Using a JavaScript solution will be easiest.

```
var myFuntion = setInterval(
function ()
{
   alert('Wow. A minute has passed';    
}, (1000 * 60)); // refresh every 60 seconds
```

In my solution, I maintain a timestamp that will help me get the new items created after the timestamp. You situation might be different. I use this timestamp in my query

```
$timeStamp = $_GET['timestamp'];
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM feed WHERE timestamp > $timeStamp";
```

In my web page, I have a Javascript function that will run periodically and call the getFeed() function

```
getFeed();

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
   getFeed();
   if (last_timestamp === undefined)
   {
        clearInterval(auto_refresh);
        last_timestamp = -1;
   }

}, (1000 * 60)); // refresh every 60 seconds
```

If you are using Yii, then you probably have JQuery loaded, so it might make sense to use that to fire off some Ajax call to the server. Notice I pass the timestamp (first time is 0.)

```
    var last_timestamp = 0;
    function getLeftPanelFeeds()
    {
        var url         = '/mycontroller/getfeed/' + last_timestamp;

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'GET',
            url         : url,
                data        : null,
            dataType    : 'html'
        })

        .done(function(data) {

            var source = $('<div>' + data + '</div>');


            var feed_update_list = source.find('#feedresult').html();
            $('#left_panel_feed').prepend(feed_update_list);

            last_timestamp = source.find('#last_timestamp').html();

        });
    }
```

Comment: i did try but not working I have updated my question with what i tried after 60 second it doesnt fetch the data from databse

Comment: I'm not sure why your code is not working. t works if I paste in in my code, However, I have updated my response to show a generic use of the setInterval() function. Try this and understand how it works, the add your custom action to the function.